# Favicon.ico will not physically show up in any browser. What do I do? :(

Tags: html, browser

I have this horrible problem with favicon.ico in my HTML page. Here's a look at my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title>Games</title>
```

I have put the favicon in the same directory as my HTML file because putting it in my resources folder didn't seem to work either. What do I do? It will not show up ANYWHERE on ANY browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in the **root web directory**. Why? Because that's what you're linking to.

Comment: But how do I do that?

Comment: Just upload it to your root web directory using ftp or scp.

Comment: I don't see how that is an issue. If you can get your HTML files on the server you should be able to do the same with a favicon. There are free ftp and scp clients out there that you can use.

Comment: No, no. I don't have no FTP or SCP clients that I'm using. I'm building it from home without any servers or web hosts.

Comment: Then just drag and drop it in your windows explorer

Comment: My favicon or my HTML file?

Comment: Or remove the leading `/`.

Answer (score 1):

use the alternate syntax:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test that the favicon works locally, change the path to wherever the `favicon.ico` file is relative to the HTML document:

If it's in a sub-directory called `foo`:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="foo/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

If it's one directory level above:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

etc.